# docker.exe files disabled in Docker Toolbox

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

Docker Toolbox had been working for me for awhile. I had been installing other things and so I restarted my computer a few times. Now, when I go to Docker, it tells me docker.exe: command not found, docker-machine: command not found. When I ls in my c/Program Files/Docker Toolbox, the .exe files are there but have asterisks appended to them. docker-compose.exe*, docker.exe*, docker-machine.exe*, etc. They are right here, why can't I run them?

Comment: Have you rebooted?

Comment: What happens if you remove the asterisks from the exe? Did they get renamed somehow?